# Raspberry pi 4 not being able to output to 4k

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, display, ubuntu

Hey so I recently got back into doing some projects with my raspberry pi, I mostly just do stuff with networking and the such, but I wanted to try to get the raspberry pi to display to 4k TV, I'm hoping to use it as a media pc. But now I've tried Raspberry pi OS and Ubuntu Desktop (64bit) and no luck. The highest is 1080p. The annoying part is I was hoping to use Ubuntu because I'm most familiar with it, and the bar at the top is off the screen cause 1080p does not line up with 4k.

Comment: What TV are you using? Are you using a micro hdmi to hdmi cable?

Comment: I bought one of those Cana kits when the pi 4 first came out and it was able to do 4k then. Also I'm using one of LG's 4k tvs. Not quite sure what model